# Effective scalar field in terms of the scale on which it emerges

Tags: effective-field-theory

Suppose there is the (pseudo)scalar field $\hat{\theta}$ with non-zero VEV $\theta$, which effectively emerges at energy scale $\Lambda$ (for example, the mass of some fermion, the scale of SSB and so on). An example is axion-like field $\theta$, which is present as
$$
\int \frac{\theta}{f_{\gamma}}F\wedge F, \quad f_{\gamma} \simeq \alpha_{\text{EM}}^{-1}\Lambda
$$
in effective action (with $F$ denoting gauge field strength).

May the quantity
$$
\epsilon \equiv \frac{\theta}{\Lambda}
$$
be many times larger than one? I.e., does some condition exist, which forbids $\epsilon >> 1$ domain? Or this is the question of our wishes, and there are no restrictions on value of $\epsilon$?

Comment: What do you mean by "effectively emerges"? The VEV is already a scale. Why should there be two scales associated with a VEV?

Comment: @flippiefanus : Is it necessary the VEV to coincide with effective scale?

Comment: Yes I would say so, unless there is some specific reason why there would have to be another scale.